# Hide a field in SharePoint based on Conditions from another field

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, sharepoint-online, calculated-columns

I have a SharePoint list that I'm using to track employee sick time. The "Actual Arrival/Departure Time"  field is meant to display the actual time that the employee arrived/departed if they weren't out for the entire day.

What I'm trying to do is hide this field and set it to 'N/A' if the "Leave Type" field is set to 'Early Departure (unscheduled)' or 'Tardy (unscheduled)'

The formula I have in here currently is:

```
=IF([Leave Type]=OR("Early Departure (unscheduled)","Tardy (unscheduled)"),TEXT([Arrival/Departure Time],"hh:mm AM/PM"), "N/A")
```

and it is a "single line of text" field.

However, the results I get when I use the early departure or tardy option is a #NAME? error and when I use anything else I get a #VALUE! error.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the formula below to achieve it.

```
=IF(OR([Leave Type]="Early Departure (unscheduled)",[Leave Type]="Tardy (unscheduled)"),"N/A",TEXT([Arrival/Departure Time],"hh:mm AM/PM"))
```

[image]

Comment: Ugh, thank you so much! What about the part of the question where I'm looking for a script that will hide this field unless Leave Type is equal to Tardy or Early Departure?

Comment: Use the formula: =IF(OR([Leave Type]="Early Departure",[Leave Type]="Tardy"),TEXT([Arrival/Departure Time],"hh:mm AM/PM"),"N/A")

Comment: If you use modern list, we can also use column formatting to achieve it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting